# Can no longer run gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Ubuntu 17.10 (X.Org), GNOME 3.26.2.

I suddenly began having this problem when I try to run `gnome-terminal`, I can't figure out what caused this:

```
main19@system19:~$ gnome-terminal

Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

This causes `gnome-terminal` not to start. I have tried looking online, everyone says it is a locale problem, here is my locale output:

```
main19@system19:~$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Output of localectl:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
VC Keymap: us
X11 Layout: us
X11 Model: pc105+inet
X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I have run out of ideas, if anyone can provide help with this that would be great.

Comment: Forgive the stupid question, but, if you run `gnome-terminal` command from a terminal... which terminal is that ?

Comment: Robert Riedl, I had to install another terminal program, I installed Sakura.

Comment: are you running this `gnome-terminal` in a su or sudo shell ?

Comment: things you can check: is `localectl` looking good ? or maybe its a [dbus issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243696/271588) ?

Comment: I am not attempting to use su or sudo or any variations of that.  

I have edited the original message to show the output of localectl.

Comment: Robert Riedl:  I finally had time to look at the dbus issue you referenced at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243696/271588 , that SEEMED to show some promise.  When I enter the command  dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all  in the Sakura terminal, then I can run gnome-terminal.....  but only for as long as I keep the Sakura terminal running.  I don't know how to make the effects of that command permanent - also, it doesn't tell me what is wrong with my system.  I learned I can do  dbus-launch gnome-terminal,  but that is merely a workaround, not a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up refreshing my HOME directory, cleaning out all kinds of old "junk" from it, paying special attention to cleaning out the .config directory.  I also created a new user so I could get a fresh copy of the .bashrc and .profile files.  This appears to have solved this (and another) problem.

Comment: Thanks!! After trying many possible workarounds and fixes, this was the step that worked! BTW - I am using cygwin-X11.

Answer (score 0):

This might be irrelevant for most, but uninstalling **chrome-remote-desktop** and then restarting the computer worked for me. The package is simple to remove:

`sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop`

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1740106).

Simply removing the extension from Chrome was not enough, possibly because I have multiple Chrome profiles with that extension. I had to uninstall it using `apt`.

The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1740106) also mentions that *simply disabling remote connections* in the extension is enough, you don't have to remove the extension entirely.

Answer (score -2):

Quickest fix: open a prompt using `Alt-F2` and run the following line:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

This cleans out all the gnome-terminal profiles. The problem might be caused by old profiles within gnome-terminal, that have unfinished command lines or invalid preferences.

(And try rebooting your system...)

**Update:**
Your problem persists over reboots, yet only in gnome-terminal. I think that means the problem should be somewhere in your configuration files for gnome-terminal.
To find out if it's just in your profile: try logging in as root using `sudo -i`.
Try `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i term` for clues.
Are there any clues in you `.profile` of `.bashrc`?

Comment: Thanks, but.....  nope.  I did as you instructed.  No discernible change, still the exact same problem.

Comment: pm-b, thanks for the suggestions, but....  I'm  sorry, I looked at the output of what you suggested, I simply am not able to decipher what it is telling me, so I don't know what is good or bad.  Also - I did not understand your last question, what is meant by the ".profile of .bashrc"?  How would I find the .profile of .bashrc?

Comment: The terminal is a "remote" through which you send commands to your computer. Whenever you start a terminal, it starts a shell (for example BASH). On startup, the shell sources a couple of files in your home folder (e.g. `.profile` and `.bashrc`), in which the general options and environment are set. Variables like `LC-*`, holding locale settings, are usually set in one of these files and sources each time the shell starts.